# Can't copy to clipboard using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to copy to clipboard a link ( the current link of the page ) using JS, but the console tells me that toCopy.select is not a function, why's that ?
Here's the code :

HTML/PHP

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="copy"><img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/img/icons/link.png" alt="link">
</a>
    <textarea id="to-copy" style="display: none;"><?php echo $current_url; ?></textarea>
```

JS

```
var toCopy = document.getElementById('to-copy'),
    btnCopy = document.getElementById('copy');

btnCopy.addEventListener('click', function () {
    toCopy.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    return false;
});
```

Can anyone tell me why ?
Thanks !

Comment: Changed it, my bad, now I don't ahve an error, but it doesn't copy to clipboard ! And I've tried a lot of things, it has never worked, I've always had an error :/

Comment: Specifically your code the problem seems to be `display: none;`, the browser can't select and copy text that it is not displaying https://jsbin.com/soquvomogu/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: I was posting my astonishing answer but then the question is locked. Just change "display: none" to "margin-left: 100%;" so that the element actually exists

Answer (score -1):

try this

```js
var copyBtn = document.querySelector('#button1');
copyBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
var textarea = document.querySelector('#textarea');
textarea.select();
var text = document.execCommand('copy'); // or 'cut'
console.log(text)
```